# How to have ListBox selected item put into Texbtox?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have textbox that auto-populates a `Listbox` as I type. Is there a way to select something in the `Listbox` and have it copy the name from the list and put it in the textbox?

```
Private Sub txtSearch_Change()

Me.txtSearch = Format(StrConv(Me.txtSearch, vbLowerCase))
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim j As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim p As Long
Me.lstdisplay.Clear
'FOR LISTBOX HEADER
Me.lstdisplay.AddItem "Server Name"
Me.lstdisplay.List(lstdisplay.ListCount - 1, 1) = "vCenter"
Me.lstdisplay.List(lstdisplay.ListCount - 1, 2) = "IP Address"
Me.lstdisplay.List(lstdisplay.ListCount - 1, 3) = "OS"
Me.lstdisplay.List(lstdisplay.ListCount - 1, 4) = "HW Version"
Me.lstdisplay.List(lstdisplay.ListCount - 1, 5) = "VCPU"
Me.lstdisplay.List(lstdisplay.ListCount - 1, 6) = "Memory"
Me.lstdisplay.List(lstdisplay.ListCount - 1, 7) = "Disk Space"

Me.lstdisplay.Selected(0) = True

For j = 1 To sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To Len(sh.Cells(j, 1))  
p = Me.txtSearch.TextLength

If LCase(Mid(sh.Cells(j, 1), x, p)) = Me.txtSearch And Me.txtSearch <> "" Then
With Me.lstdisplay
.AddItem sh.Cells(j, 1)

.List(lstdisplay.ListCount - 1, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(j, 13)
.List(lstdisplay.ListCount - 1, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(j, 7)
.List(lstdisplay.ListCount - 1, 3) = Sheet1.Cells(j, 9)
.List(lstdisplay.ListCount - 1, 4) = Sheet1.Cells(j, 8)
.List(lstdisplay.ListCount - 1, 5) = Sheet1.Cells(j, 3)
.List(lstdisplay.ListCount - 1, 6) = Sheet1.Cells(j, 4)
.List(lstdisplay.ListCount - 1, 7) = Sheet1.Cells(j, 5)

End With
End If
Next x
Next j

End Sub
```

That's my `txtSearch_change` and it works great.  I just want them to be able to select something from the `listbox` and have it overwrite whats in the `txtSearch.Text` box?

Answer (score 0):

If understood correctly: double click on your lstdisplay control and select it's change event (or copy/paste this):

```
Private Sub lstdisplay_Change()
    Me.txtSearch.Text = Me.lstdisplay.Text
End Sub
```